# Python k-means get error Found array with 0 feature(s)

Tags: python, k-means

I am trying to read a csv file and apply k-means algorithm to identify the groups of the elements.

My code is this:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from sklearn import cluster as sk

print(sk.k_means(np.genfromtxt('keywords.csv', delimiter=' ')[:,:0],3))
```

I use `genfromtxt` because there are some missing values and with this statement I can bypass these.

For the moment I would like to see the full return of the `k_means` function but I get

```
/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:59: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)
/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:70: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ejercicio2.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(sk.k_means(np.genfromtxt('keywords.csv', delimiter=' ')[:,:0],3))
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 345, in k_means
    x_squared_norms=x_squared_norms, random_state=random_state)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 388, in _kmeans_single_elkan
    X = check_array(X, order="C")
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 424, in check_array
    context))
ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(3312, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

Comment: @hashcode55 Thanks for your answer. If I change to [:0,:] I get the same error but shape (shape=(0, 3703))

Comment: @hashcode55 That's the answer! Thank you! Post it and I vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing all the rows but no columns by writing `[:, :0]` and hence the error. You might want to send all the rows and columns, and in that case just remove it from that line. In general the syntax is -

`data[x:y, a:b]`

which just means, rows from x to y(exclusive) and columns from a to b(exclusive).